# If $n>1$, the square of the odd Fibonacci number $F(2n+1)$ can be written as the sum of exactly $F(2n+1)+1$ nonzero squares.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, differential-topology, analytic-number-theory, 4-manifolds

While reading a paper by Owens (arXiv:1906.05913) about embeddings of rational homology balls in the complex projective plane, I found out the following somewhat unexpected number theory corollary (here $F(n)$ denotes the $n$-th Fibonacci number, with $F(1)=1$ and $F(2)=1$).

If $n>1$, the square of the odd Fibonacci number $F(2n+1)$ can be written as the sum of exactly $F(2n+1)+1$ nonzero squares.

I will put an answer with the proof. However, I am curious about whether a proof of this result can be obtained by purely numer-theoretic methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from a result in Conway's  little book *The Sensual Quadratic Form,*  and a bit of computation, that  every number $n \geq 34$  is the sum of five nonzero squares. That missing number $33$  is a one-off. There is a proof in Niven and Zuckerman  where $34$  is replaced by the easier $170,$   pages 318-319 in the Fifth edition (with Montgomery, 1991).

With $k \geq 6:$  any number $n \geq k + 14$   can be expressed as the sum of $k$  nonzero squares.

The numbers that are not the sum of five nonzero squares are:
$  1,2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18, 33 $
This list is at [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A047701)  with references

not six:
$1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 16, 19.$

**The induction step**: if $n \geq n_k$  means that $n$ is the sum of $k$ nonzero squares, then $ n \geq 1 + n_k$ means that $n$ is the sum of $1+k$ nonzero squares

Comment: Thank you! It was reasonable to expect it to be a consequence of something much more general. How do you prove that any number $n \ge k +14$ can be expressed as the sum of $k$ nonzero squares for $k \ge 6$?

Comment: @trilobita  Conway gives the numbers not four nonzero squares. There are infinitely many but they are sparse. For $n > 50,$ say, either $n-1$   or $n-4$ or $n-9$   is the sum of four nonzero squares, hence $n$ itself is five. Next, if $ n \geq n_k$   means it is the sum of $k$  nonzero squares, then $n \geq 1 + n_k$  means it is the sum of $1+k$ nonzero squares.

Comment: @trilobita   the book is available at https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/conwaysens.pdf  while the result used is on page 140, just called Theorem.  I suspect the lists  for four and five squares would be on the OEIS, let me check

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Owens proves that if $n>1$ the rational homology ball $B_{F(2n+1),F(2n-1)}$ can be embedded smoothly but not symplectically in $\mathbb{CP}^2$. From Donaldson's Theorem, Owens obtains an obstruction to the existence of such embeddings (Proposition 3.2). In particular, the intersection lattice $\Lambda_M$ of the complement of $B_{F(2n+1),F(2n-1)}$ in $\mathbb{CP}^2$, which has rank $1$ by Lemma 3.1, must embed in $\mathbb{Z}^{F(2n+1)+1}$, and its image must intersect nontrivially each unit vector. Since a generator of $\Lambda_M$ has self-pairing $F(2n+1)^2$, the conclusion follows.

Answer (score -1):

Comment:This is just for some information. It probably can be used for an analytic answer to question.

We know :

$$\Sigma^{n}_{i=1} F_i^2=F_n\times F_{n+1}$$

Also:

$$F_n^2=F_{n-1}\times F_{k+1}+(-1)^{n-1}$$

Multiplying both sides by $F_n$ we obtain:

$$F_n^2\times F_n=F_{n-1}\times(F_n\cdot F_{(n+1)})+(-1)^{n-1}$$

Dividing both sides by $F_{n-1}$ we get:

$$F_n\times \Phi=\Sigma^n_{i=1} F_I^2+(-1)^{n-1}\times \Phi$$

If $n=2k+1$ then:

$$\Phi\big(F^2_{(2k+1)}-1\big)=\Sigma^{2k+1}_{i=1} F_i^2$$

The number of terms on RHS is $(2k+1)$.

Comment: I don't get it. Could you please write out your representations of $25$  as the sum of $6$  nonzero squares, then $169$   as the sum of $14$ nonzero squares?

Comment: There is something which does not convince me: your last formula would imply that $\sum_{i=1}^{2k} F_i^2+1=0$. Also, $25=9+9+4+1+1+1$, and I think this is the only possibility

Comment: Also, the number of terms on the RHS of your last formula is $(2k+1)+1$, not $F_{2k+1}+1$